# Чи можна сказати "на тому боці річки"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Виконуючи переклад я переклав частину речення "...on the other side of the river" ("Beneath a Scarlet Sky) як "на іншому боці річки". Однак, мій викладач сказав, що у річки не може бути "боків", і варто було перекласти "на іншому березі річки".

Тому я [перевірив синоніми](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3) до слова "берег" і виявив, що "бік" та "берег" взагалі не є синонімами. У СУМі я також не знайшов тлумачення для слова "бік", яке б означало те саме, що й слово "берег". Однак, загугливши словосполучення "бік річки", я знайшов його у книзі "Князь Єремія Вишневецький" ("По один бік річки стояла шляхетська Польща...").

Також на [цьому сайті](https://ru.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%20%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8), переклад речення: "Прямо перед мостом через реку Огден мы увидели, как из бара, стоявшего на северном берегу реки, вышел человек" було виконано як: "Коли ми майже вже з’їжджали з мосту через Огден-Рівер, із шинка, що був якраз на північному боці ріки, вийшов чоловік".

Отож, все таки чи можна сказати "боки річки" та "на тому боці річки", чи краще вживати слово "берег"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У [СЛОВНИКУ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ ONLINE](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=4338&page=162) надано 7 значень слова бік, окрім фразеологічних зворотів. Одне з них:

> 3. Місце, місцевість, що лежить не посередині, а збоку від кого-, чого-небудь. Ой заграй, заграй, синесеньке море, Та під тими
>      байдаками, Що пливуть козаки .. Та на сей бік за нами (Т. Шевченко);
>      За станцією починався яр, по другий бік колії лежав степ (П. Панч); *
>      Образно. Говорю і цілую – сльозою вже став З того боку снігів – цього
>      боку немає (М. Вінграновський).

У шевченковому уривку йдеться про *бік моря*, яке, за логікою вашого викладача, теж не повинно мати боків. Якщо дивитися на ріку за течією, з її обох боків - береги. Але якщо думати російською мовою і перекладати *бік* як *бок*, а не *сторона*, то зміст його зауваження зрозумілий, хоча української мови не стосується.

Answer (score 4):

Так, бік не є синонімом до берега. Але у випадку коли ріка виступає як територіальна межа, за якою щось знаходиться, тому використання "боку" ріки цілком можливе. Це особливо помітно коли по той бік ріки знаходяться якісь інші географічні об'єкти - яри, озера, тощо.

Наприклад:

> На східному боці річки Лопушки, що впадала в Кінську, проти села Маячки, розкинулось багато озер, а з них найбільше, рахуючи згори: Царград, Глибоке, Довге, Криве (це вже вкотре?), Розкопанка, Глухе, Осикове, Білоцерковне, Орлове, Річище, Прошесь, Тихе, Волове, знову Криве та Бабине, прозване так через те, що на ньому збиралися баби (пелікани). Опріч озер, понад Кінською йшли лимани: Холодний, Дурний, Буроватий, Скелюватий, Крутоватий та інші.
>
> *"[В глибині Великого Лугу](http://www.myslenedrevo.com.ua/uk/Lit/K/KaschenkoA/Popular/VelykyjLug/VGlybyniVelykogoLugu.html)" - Адріан Кащенко*

У цьому прикладі озера знаходяться не на самому березі ріки, а на східній частині простору який розділяється рікою.

Так само у моря є береги, але цілком вживаним є "цей бік моря". Приклад у СУМ-11:

> **[БІК](http://sum.in.ua/s/bik),** боку, чол.
> 3. Місце, місцевість, що знаходиться не посередині, збоку чого-небудь. Ой заграй, заграй, синесеньке море, Та під тими байдаками, Що пливуть козаки.. Та на сей бік за нами (Тарас Шевченко, I, 1951, 199); За станцією починався яр, по другий бік колії лежав степ (Петро Панч, Синів.., 1959, 4).